# Print a specific key from json file

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to print a specific key from a dictionary(key:value) like this in a JSON file(below). I tried this code but prints everything:

reda.json:

```json
[{"alice": 24, "bob": 27}, {"carl": 33}, {"carl": 55}, {"user": "user2"}, {"user": "user2"}, {"user": "123"},]
```

Python:

```py
import json
filename = 'reda.json'

json_data = json.load(open('reda.json'))
if type(json_data) is dict:
    json_data = [json_data]
for i in json_data:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `print(f"{i}:{json_data[i]}")` in the last line

Comment: But this iteration prints all the key value pairs, what is the specific key you are looking for in the example?

Comment: i want to print lets say "carl" 's value

Comment: This is a list of 6 dictionaries and "carl" is a key in two of them.  What *exactly* do you want? Your code isn't even *trying* to look for "carl".

Comment: Its ok , the solution J_H gave worked for me , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* turn the list of dicts into a single dict.
Downside is dups would be squished, so e.g. "carl" would map to just a single number.

As it stands, you probably want to see all of carl's values,
using something like this:

```
json_data = json.load(open('reda.json'))
for d in json_data:
    print(d)

k = "carl"
print(f"\nHere is {k}:")
for d in json_data:
    if k in d:
        print(k, d[k])
```

---

To see if e.g. "carl" is in the data, use this:

```
def contains_favorite_key(d: dict, k="carl"):
    return k in d

if any(map(contains_favorite_key, json_data)):
    print("found at least one occurrence!")
```

---

To say "bye, bye, Carl!" use `del`:

```
k = "carl"
assert k in d
print(d[k])

del d[k]

print(d[k])  # Notice that this now reports KeyError.
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, Is there any i could check if a key exist inside?

Comment: wow thanks for that too, Well tbh Python is support is fast compared to any language here, and i can say this is the very reason i want to learn it

Comment: One more thing sir, how do i delete a key and its value from it ?